# Forcing generated CSV to download when run as cron on server

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron, centos

I'm trying to get an export to CSV script to download to the server when run as a cronjob but also still work via web.

When I run the script from web it forces a CSV to download which is great, however when I run it on the server (CentOS Server) it just echos the file contents instead.

I need it to download the file into the area defined in the **cronjob**.

```
//OK lets export
include("config.php");
$table = "data";
$filename = "Export_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i");

header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . ".csv");

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('artist', 'title', 'presenter', 'timeplayed'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db('prs');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE timeplayed >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24     HOUR ORDER BY id DESC');
if($rows === FALSE) 
{
  die(mysql_error()); 
}

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Anyone with any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html)?

Comment: Using `headers()` is pretty meaningless in a cron script - because there's no browser to download to: this is what comes with cut-and-pasting somebody elses code without trying to understand what it is actually doing .... why not write to an actual filesystem filename rather than `php://output`? You're even defining a filename (`$filename = "Export_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i");`) without ever using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

```
php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism 
             in the same way as print and echo.
```

That really says it all.

So when you run this from a browser the standard output mechanism is `send it to the browser` as that is what `echo` or `print` would do. But in PHP CLI mode it sends the output to the terminal.

Answer is change this line from

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

to

```
$output = fopen($filename, 'w');
```

You then just have to decide if you are running through the browser or the CLI(cron job) and [here is a suggestion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

```
if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
    header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . ".csv");
    readfile($filename);
}
```

You are going to have to check what your system reports using `php_sapi_name()` just to be sure you are testing for the right condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I have tried using
    $output = fopen($filename, 'w');
But what happens is it gets permission denied errors, I presumed because it can't find the file because it isn't yet created? Same when reading the file

It manages to run in the terminal but the file output is blank :-(

Comment: That sounds like a permission issue. Check that the user running the cron, and the user that Apache runs as is allowed to create files in that folder!

Comment: Turns out it was because I hadn't defined it to go a specific folder which has the permissions! Derp!

Changed it so that it goes to the correct folder and now it's writing to it properly! Hurrah! Thank you for your help!